# Admin sidebar element buggy on hover with Google Chrome 45

Tags: admin, wp-admin, sidebar, google-chrome

I'm using `OSX 10.10` `Google Chrome Version 45.0.2454.85 (64-bit)` And When I go through the sidebar elements on my Wordpress site it looks like this:

[image]

Is this a known bug?.

On Firefox and Safari everything is looking fine.

**UPDATE 1**

You can temporary fix this by adding this on your `functions.php` file template:

```
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', function (){ 
    if ( strpos( $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Chrome' ) !== false ){
         wp_add_inline_style( 'wp-admin', '#adminmenu { transform: translateZ(0); }' );
    }
});
```

**UPDATE 2**
This has been reported on Google Chrome forums: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/vRbjCc-eafw;context-place=forum/chrome